# How to Echo Different Link Address According to it's Email Address?

Tags: php, optimization, hyperlink

So, i have this scenario in registering form:

```
<p>Here is your email: <?php echo '<a href="link here">'.$_SESSION['email'].'</a>'; ?></p>
```

Now for the `href=""` I need to echo different link for every different text echoed by `$_SESSION['email']`.

Is it possible to request link from server, or services from each different email company?

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
<?php 
  echo '<a href="mailto:'.$_SESSION['email'].'">'.$_SESSION['email'].'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't remember the `mailto` function, how stupid of me.